# Use cases of Amazon cloud-formation

Tags: amazon-web-services

What is the use of amazon cloud formation. Is there any addition pricing of amazon cloud formation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you start with reading a bit here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html

CloudFormation is a tool for automated Infrastructure deployment and management in AWS. Ofcourse, that is really high-level overview without any detials. It can do A LOT of things.

About your second question the answer is: No, CloudFormation doesn't cost you anything, the pricing on provisioned resources though, is still the same. 
In other words, you won't pay for templates in CloudFormation or their usage, but you will still pay for what CloudFormation has created for you as Infrastructure.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much TenorFlyy

Answer (score 1):

Cloud formation is a free service. It is just a template ( set of structured instructions) used to provision resources.

The resources created will be charged.

USE CASE:
--For example, you have 10 AWS accounts. In each account, you wish to have an EC2 instance,an Auto-scaling group etc etc.

--So in each account, you have to manually login, create an ASG, create an EC2 instance which is time taking.

--Here you can have a cloud-formation template, where under the resources section, you can create EC2 instances, ASG etc.

--Thus, in a single click, i.e by uploading this template, you will have the resources created.

Hope this helps